# Complex multi-level JSON and SQL - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, json

So I am able to query my JSON file fine then I wanted to add another field that is under a few levels and when I try to do this - it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

So the following works correctly and gives me back the first level promoter id

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\test\test.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.events[0].promoters[0]')
WITH 
(
    [promoterid] varchar(10) '$.promoter.id'

)
```

This does not work - I get all my fields back **except** that darn promoter id

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\test\test.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.events') 
WITH 
(
  [venueName]        varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueName',
  [venueId]          varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueId',
  [legacyVenueId]    varchar(20)  '$.venue.legacyVenueId',
  [venueZipCode]     varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueZipCode',
  [venueStreet]      varchar(50)  '$.venue.venueStreet',
  [venueCity]        varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueCity',
  [venueStateCode]   varchar(10)  '$.venue.venueStateCode',
  [venueCountryCode] varchar(10)  '$.venue.venueCountryCode',
  [minPrice]         varchar(10)  '$.minPrice',
  [promoterId]       varchar(10)  '$.promoters.promoter.id'
)
```

Comment: Please add the content of a sample JSON input file.

Comment: File with two entries in link (file is too long for me to put here in a comment - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnYSQrM0Cc3pCjBYXr4FW8tDwAXB21Xl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Will you always have at most one promoter for each event? The JSON looks like it may allow multiple promoters. In this case is it ok to have multiple rows returned for the same event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question - I finally figured it out with help from this site - https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/11/01/reading-json-string-with-nested-elements-sql-server-2016-part-3/

This is what works -

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\test\test.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) import
select 
json_value (c.value, '$.venue.venueName') as venueName,
json_value (c.value, '$.venue.venueId') as venueID,
json_value (p.value, '$.promoter.id') as promoterID

from openjson(@json, '$.events') as c
cross apply openjson (c.value, '$.promoters') as p
```